# How to Differentiate Hard Drive models in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, wmi, hard-drive

I am currently using a WMI query to return the manufacturer name of all hard disks connected to a computer. Unfortunately this doesn't specifically return "Intel" or "Western Digital" so I am using string.Contains() to compare who the manufacturer is. 
My code in simple form is:

```
        //*** Declare Management Class
        ManagementClass clsMgtClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
        ManagementObjectCollection colMgtObjCol = clsMgtClass.GetInstances();

        //*** Loop Over Objects

        foreach (ManagementObject objMgtObj in colMgtObjCol)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(objMgtObj.Properties["Manufacturer"].Value.ToString());
        }
```

This works maybe 60% of the time, because it relies on the WMI to return the whole name. So for example my hard drive is returned as "SanDisk SDSSDX240GG25 ATA Device" which is fine because I can locate "SanDisk" quite easily. Likewise, Western Digital products will show up as "WD3000USB" or something like that, where I can clearly find "WD". However on another computer using a Seagate drive, it has SE1000GXB blah blah and doesn't have any real indication of the manufacturer. So my question is, how could I reliably find out the hard drive manufacturer, and be able to easily differentiate between manufacturers without having to go to all the trouble of querying model numbers through a google script or database. Thanks. 
Another edit: using the member "Caption", it will return the examples above. Using the member "Manufacturer" will simply return "(Standard Disk Drives)"

Comment: http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=921544 helps, the model number I mentioned above was ST31000340AS which fits in to this prefix calculator, but it isn't the most elegant solution. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I cannot find alternatives to wmi for getting a well formed human readable manufacturer name for disk drives. Can you run the script on the network and then get a count of unique manufacturer names? Or am I missing the point....

Comment: I could jJack, but that would simply be compiling a list of HDD ID's which I could easily do on the internet. After a while of searching, it appears the only solution will be to find out unique patterns or combinations that can distinguish between manufacturers.

Comment: This is how they appear in Device Manager, so I don't think you are going to get anything better. Device Manager also shows Manufacturer as "(Standard Disk Drives)".

Comment: Might be possible to use regex expressions to look for acronym and abbreviation patterns. Or some other way to measure levenshtein distance between what wmi returns against a 'friendly' name. Libraries exist for this type of problem, would that be something you're willing to explore?

Comment: Thanks Michael, that confirms my suspicion. 
To jJack: I think that will be getting too extensive, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

ST - seagate

You could download a list of model number prefixes from each of the now merged hard disk companies and make a table out of the models, this table could contain the actual capacities as well if you wished.

Model numbers typically have enough information in them, serial numbers on disk devices after 1986 typically contain model information in them.

Bottom line, you may have to create a table to lookup the information in a human friendly way.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/listhdds_2k.txt

this will help you know what merged
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_hard_disk_manufacturers

here's a batch file for windows
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=listhdds_2k